# Compressing a file from memory with SevenZipSharp, stranges mistakes

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, 7zip

I download the SevenZipSharp Lib in order to compress some files.

I used this in order to compress a file :

```
var libPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "7-zip", "7z.dll");
SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(libPath);
SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.CompressFiles(@"C:\myTestFile.mdf", new string[] { @"C:\myTestFileCompressed.7z" });
```

With this, my file is compressed whitout problem. I can decompressed it.

Now...i would like to compress the same file, but, instead of compress directly the file, i would like to :

- Read the file in a string. Yes, in a string, and not in a byte[].
- - Convert my string to byte[]
    Compress the byte[] to another byte[].

**Here is my try :**

```
string strToCompress = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myTestFile.mdf");
SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
byte[] byteArrayToCompress = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayToCompress);
MemoryStream streamOut = new MemoryStream();
compressor.CompressStream(stream, streamOut);
string strcompressed = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(streamOut.ToArray());
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myfileCompressed.7z",strcompressed);
```

**My problem is very simple :**

If i compare the size produced by these 2 methods, it's 3 603 443 bytes vs 3 604 081 bytes. 
In addition, i cannot uncompressed the file produced by the second method.

Maybe it's because i used ASCII encoding, but my file to compress is not a Text, it's a binary file.

Anyone could explain me how solving it please ? I need to read my file to a string and compress it. ( i don't want to read the file directly to a byte[]).

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put binary data into a string, not every byte value has a Unicode codepoint.  Using ASCII encoding will similarly always cause irretrievable data loss, it only has characters for byte values 0 through 127, higher values will produce a ?

You certainly can convert a byte[] to a string, it needs to be *encoded*.  The standard encoding that's used for that is available in .NET from the Convert.ToBase64String() method.  You recover the byte[] again with Convert.FromBase64String().  Inevitably it won't be as compact, it will be 4/3 bigger as the original data in a byte[].

You can never produce a valid .7z archive that way, it of course uses the most compact possible storage and that is bytes.  You must pass a FileStream to the CompressStream() method.